# Язык СИ, два раза Scanf()

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
 int kkk=1; int s, w;
    char r;
    char k;


    while(kkk==1){

    init_chessboard();
    print_chessboard();


            printf("Zadaj(S,R):");
            scanf("%c%i", &r,&s);
            printf("vyp %c%i\n",r,s);


            printf("Zadaj nov(S,R):");
            scanf("%c%i", &k, &w);
            printf("vyp %c%i\n", k, w);



    getchar();

    }

}
```

`
Код программы внизу. Проблема в том, что я прошу задать в сканф символ и число (букву по вертикале и число по горизонтали ), первый сканф срабатывает нормально, а второй нет. Второй сканф переносит на другую строку и "67" пишет постоянно. Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: код]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавте код текстом.

Comment: Вероятно `scanf("%c%d",...)`

Comment: scanf - это зло, надёжнее разбирать строки руками. При чем тут дальнейшее? вы присваиваете переменным значение, и после scanf текста у вас больше нет

Comment: ок, как разбирать руками?

Comment: Цикл for, использовать автомат, прогонять через switch - вариантов много, зависит от задачи парсинга.

Comment: После первого `scanf` в буфере остается символ новой строки.

Comment: да, знаю, писал это, только из-за этого и сделал эту запись, не знал как изменить сканф что бы убрать перенос на новую строку.